# How to set font weight to "bold" in gnuplot 5+ for SVG terminal?

Tags: svg, fonts, gnuplot

In gnuplot version 5+ (release candidate when this question was asked) the SVG terminal has the parameters `fname 'Arial'` and `fsize 15` (Arial with size 15, for example). The SVG terminal also supports enhanced text mode (sub and super scripts, font weight, etc.) for own text labels by saying something like `{/Arial:Bold=20 my text}`.

**But how can I set the font weight globally, so that also the tick marks use it?**

When I write `fname 'Arial:Bold'` into the terminal options, the produced SVG has `font-family="Arial:Bold"` and not `font-family="Arial" font-weight="Bold"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky, the `svg` terminal currently is the only(?) terminal which allows this. You can use the `fname` terminal option to specify both a font family and a font weight (with the `font` option you can only select a font family:

```
set terminal svg standalone fname 'Arial bold' fsize 15
set xlabel 'xlabel'
set ylabel 'ylabel'
set output 'arial-bold.svg'
plot x
```

Note, however, that with these settings you cannot set a single label to normal font weight (could be a bug) with `set label '{/:Normal Normal weight}'`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. :) Where can I look these things up? The official gnuplot docs have very few details about font options/syntax/possibilities for the different terminals.

Comment: The option `fname` is mentioned for the svg terminal, but its use isn't documented although it was already introduced in october 2011 (before 4.6). I came across it and its usage when looking through the sources to see how `font` is handled and if it has some hidden features to allow selecting a bold font.